# How can I remove an N3 type connector from a Canon 7D Mark II?

Tags: canon, remote

I have a Canon 7D Mark II and I bought a corded shutter remote button from Amazon in the beginning of 2023, I just recently plugged the N3 plug up to the camera to test it. Works fine but I can not get it to unplug from the camera body. Is there a release lock to this plug and if so how does it work?

Comment: You'll find it easier if you register your account. You'll also be notified if there are any comments or replies. If you lose or delete your cookies after leaving this page, you won't otherwise be able to interact with the question again. BTW, answers don't have titles, questions have titles. Answers will all be below that.

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://photography.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://photography.stackexchange.com/help), to give yourself an idea as to how Stack Exchange works.

Comment: A photo of the cable inserted into the camera or a link to the listing on amazon would help. There are a multitude of third party cables with N3 ends. We have no way of knowing how yours is made unless it is the official Canon Remote Switch RS-80N3.

Answer (score 2):

As far as my research goes, there is no lock mechanism in the N3 connector, you just have to pull.

Comment: Agreed, there is no lock on any of the common plug mechanisms (USB, C1/C2, N1/N2/N3, S1/S2, etc)... although N1 does have a screw locking collar you can engage if you want.

Comment: I had a third party N3 cable one time that did have a lock collar. The spring loaded collar had to be pulled back in order to pull the cable out of the camera. It was cheaply made and didn't last long before it came apart. I have no idea what the little "hooks" grabbed on the camera, but they were grabbing something.